# Does LiteIDE support "go to previous" shortcut?

Tags: go

I'm looking at the keybindings for LiteIDE and I'm trying to figure out how to "go to previous". 
E.G. you mouse over a function, click "go to definition" then you want to quickly get back to where you  were. Usually most ide's have that as CMD + Left Arrow but I cannot seem to figure it out for LiteIDE.

Is this possible in version X22?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Linux, Alt-Left and Alt-Right do it. Perhaps this maps to Option-Left and Option-Right on OS X. If not, or if you don't like that key combo, you could go to the View menu, choose Options, and go to the Keyboard tab, and find the Backward and Forward commands and assign them different bindings.

Comment: beautiful! thanks.. I was looking for shortcuts named "previous"/"next", totally looked past "backward" and "forward" in the keymapping. works now

Comment: Out of curiosity, is it Opt-Left/Right on Mac? If so, I'll edit the "perhaps" out for a clearer answer.